# Binary addition and subtraction 2s complement and signed and magnitude

Tags: math, binary

I am computing the binary subtraction of these 2 numbers:

10011000 (-24) from 10101011 (-43)

I converted 10101011 to 2s complement:
01010101 then added both numbers since we are doing a subtraction and get this:
11101101 which is negative 19.
Here’s how I computed that:

-128 + 64 + 32 + 8 + 4 + 1

But, if I convert the result using 2s complement again, I get positive 19 as expected.

Why must I convert again using 2s complement?

Comment: Why did  you only convert one value to 2's complement?

Comment: What subtraction? In your own words, "I am computing the binary addition of these 2 numbers", showing -24 and -43, so there is no subtraction?

Comment: Oh my bad, it was a typo.

Comment: It matters which term you flip. If you want to calculate `a - b` then the two's complement addition is `a + two(b)` rather than the `two(a) + b` that you used. So: instead of using the two's complement of -43, use the two's complement of -24.